# c++ error: no instance of function template

Tags: c++, lua, function-templates

I'am trying to get a variable out of my config.lua file with c++. 
I've created a Lua-Class from a tutorial to get these variable but I'am getting an error 
when I try to call the function who gets the variable from config.lua

here are the code snippets:

```
LuaScript script("config.lua");
script.get(string("test"));
```

I'am getting the error, "no instance of function template matches the argument list", at the point where I call "script.get(string("test));"

the template function and specialization looks like this:

```
template<typename T>
T get( const std::string &variableName )
{
    if (!L)
    {
        printError(variableName, "Script not loaded");
        return lua_getdefault<T>();
    }

    T result;
    if (lua_gettostack(variableName))
    {
        result = lua_get<T>(variableName);
    }else{
        result = lua_getdefault<T>();
    }

    clean();
    return result;
}
```

the specialization:

```
template<>
inline std::string LuaScript::lua_get<std::string>( const std::string &variableName )
{
std::string s = "null";
if (lua_isstring(L, -1))
{
    s = std::string(lua_tostring(L, -1));
}else{
    printError(variableName, "Not a string");
}

return s;
}
```

Just for some more information, I'am coding and compiling with Visual Studio 2012.

thanks for your help :)

Comment: `LuaScript::lua_get` **is not a specialization** of the function template (`get()`) you show.

Comment: so do I need to write a specialization or is my error somewhere else? because the get() function calls the lua_getdefault

Comment: whoever downvoted, why the downvote? OP didn't say the specialization was for get(); they correctly showed the specialization of lua_get<T> for string since that is the one they thought was being instantiated (but wasn't, as per my answer).

Comment: @Schollii I didn't downvote anything here?!?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Sorry, I guess the downvoter didn't leave a comment, unfortunate. I edited my comment.

Comment: @Schollii De nada! But I think the question was originally downvoted because it's not asked very clear, and using the term _specialization_ wrongly. I didn't downvote, but AFAIR I also [honestly decided](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) the question wasn't worth upvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler does not know `T` of your templated `get()` since it is only a return value (and even if you were to assign the return value to a variable, C++ does not infer `T` based on return values). So you must explicitly tell compiler what is `T`. Also, you do not need to create the temp string, since there is only one parameter type possible (`const std::string&`), so try this:

```
script.get<std::string>("test");
```